# How to save an ls of my desktop onto a folder on my desktop as a txt file? In one line/step

Tags: linux, ls, mv

i was doing something thinking and wanted to understand if i could save information on to folder.
I know i can do it in many steps, create the file, then move it to a folder. But is there a one step command ?

I tried something like this. Trying to get files/folder list and total number as well..that is why i use wc -l as well. how to combine these?

ls | wc -l > desktop_intel.txt foldername

I think it doesn't work.
What if i want to safe this as text on a usb drive for instance ?
Thank you !

Comment: Use `tee` command to get output of `ls` and send it to `wc`

Comment: Note that on Unix, BSD--and Linux, too--they are "directories" and not the Windows graphical concept of "folders" which is not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, something like the following should work.

```
ls desktop/ > desktop/foldername/desktop_intel.txt
```

This assumes a `desktop/` subdirectory is in your current directory.

Note in your example it's unclear what you're trying to accomplish with the `wc -l` as there is no mention of needing a word count in your description.

If you want to save to a USB, you would need a path to the mount point (which is just a directory) for the USB drive, you can try commands like `mount` and `df` to get that path, and then redirect the output from the `ls` command to that directory.

Comment: Question is how to save ls output and count number of files simultaneously.